# Prove the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r} \binom{n}{k} = 3^n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r} \binom{n}{k} = 3^n$. I believe I need to use the binomial theorem here, but I don't know how to deal with the double summations.

Comment: Use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525266/prove-sum-binom-nk-2k-3n-using-the-binomial-theorem).

Comment: You may be interested in the [Multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) about multinomial coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will use the identity
$$
\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{k-r}\quad (n\geq k\geq r\geq 0).
$$
Interchange the order of summation and use the identity above to get that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r} \binom{n}{k}
=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{n-r}{k-r}=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}2^{n-r}=(1+2)^n=3^n 
$$
where we used the fact that
$$
\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{n-r}{k-r}=\sum_{u=0}^{n-r}\binom{n-r}{u}=2^{n-r}.
$$

Comment: Do you know a combinatorial proof of the statement?

Comment: @mathnoob I think I have a combinatorial argument, see my answer below.

Comment: That's cool! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You know that $\displaystyle(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkx^k$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r} \binom{n}{k} =\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r}1^r$

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r}1^r=(1+1)^k=2^k$, we have

$\displaystyle\implies\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom nk2^k=(1+2)^n=3^n$

Answer (score 4):

Let $|X|=n$, so $3^n$ is the number of functions from $X$ to {$1,2,3$}.

Each such function corresponds uniquely to a pair of subsets $(A,B)$ with $A$ a subset of $B$ and $B$ a subset of $X$ by taking $B$ = {$x$ | $f(x)=2$ or $f(x)=3$} and $A$ = {$x$ | $f(x)=2$}.

The number of such pairs of nested subsets of $X$ is the double sum on the right hand side of the formula (where $k$ = $|B|$ and $r$ = $|A|$).

Answer (score 3):

> A convenient aspect is the index of the inner sum affects only one binomial coefficient. Setting parenthesis we might observe
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r}\binom{n}{k}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r} \right)\binom{n}{k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^k \binom{n}{k}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=3^n}
> \end{align*}